# Django: How to disable ordering in model

Tags: python, django

Let's say there is a model with default ordering described in Meta class

```
class People(models.Model):
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = (last_name, first_name)
```

Is there are a way to get unordered queryset

Comment: Why do you need an unordered set? Do you need it to be random?

Comment: in fact my table have ~ 400 000 records, and disabling ordering will speed up database query a lot, so it is some kind of optimization

Comment: If that is always the case(many records) then it may be better to remove the default ordering in the Meta class.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can just override by simply adding .order_by()

for example:

```
People.objects.all().order_by()
```

This will make sure that Meta ordering is overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Using an empty order_by() worked for queries with filters.

BUT asking for the .first() element was problematic and always resulted in ORDER BY.
To overcome this what I did was a little bit ugly:

```
People.objects.all().order_by()[:1].values_list(...)[0]
```

This effectively removes the ORDER BY, and avoids the problem that asking for [:1][0] where it would get optimized and add it anyway. At the moment I don't know about other workarounds, but I'd love to hear them. I tried doing the above code without the values_list, but in that case Django always tried to perform the Order By.